# ExtJS hbox draggable vertical line

Tags: javascript, extjs, containers, hbox

In ExtJS 4.2.2. I have an hbox container like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
  width: 500,
  height: 300,
  title: "HBoxLayout Panel",
  layout: {
    type: 'hbox',
    align: 'stretch'
  },
  renderTo: document.body,
  items: [{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Inner Panel One',
    flex: 2
  },{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Inner Panel Two',
    flex: 1
  },{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Inner Panel Three',
    flex: 1
  }]
});
```

It is just the example in the docs. But i want the vertical line between the three different panels to be draggable, so the user is able to adjust the size of each panel.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe I should add a question to it. My question is "how do i do it, so the vertical line is draggable?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [Splitter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.resizer.Splitter). Between your panels, add:

```
{xtype: 'splitter'}
```

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/r4h

Comment: You are awesome. So simple but I wasn't able to find it. Thank you very much

Comment: You can also use a border layout, instead of hbox, and set the items to 'split: true'. It depends on what you want..

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/layout/border.html